# Issue parent() in jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, csquery

Imagine some HTML code :

```
<div class="container">  
   <div class="first">
     <a class="result"> </a> 
   </div>

   <div class="second">
      <a class="result"> </a> 
  </div>
</div>
```

and

```
$("a.result:first").parent().select('a');
```

As I think it must return a in div.first, right?

Because when I do this logic in CsQuery it's return a in div.first and div.second.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: The jQuery [`.select` function](http://api.jquery.com/select/) expects a function as argument. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Maybe you should use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/select/) instead of `select`.

Comment: I guess it would be helpful if you post the exact csquery function call you are using.

Comment: It seems to be working http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BRDqV/

Comment: I think you have to primarily clarify one thing: Is your issue with jQuery or CsQuery?

Comment: I using CsQuery. The problem is - if I use this selector in CsQuery          $("a.result:first").parent().select('a')    it's return me both of a.

But, if I will create new instance of CsQuery before use function "select", it's return me only first a. 

for example:      
 new CQ($("a.result:first").parent().RenderSelection()).Select('a');

I tried debug that in source code and find out that if I use first variant new CQ inherit previous selection (it's clearly normal), but why then when I trying to find smt it's search in ALL document?...

Comment: in CsQuery `Select` operates against the whole DOM, so `$("a.result:first").parent().select('a')` (if it were valid C# code) would be the same as `$('a')`. Perhaps what you want is `$("a.result:first").parent().find('a')`. The `find` method (in both CsQuery and jQuery) searches the children of the selected elements, and not the entire DOM.

Comment: Is it correct that function "select" in CsQuery working like that? 

if yes, when I can use it? Because I don't understand that...

Comment: @user2263827 Jamie is the author and lead developer of CsQuery. If he said that's the way it acts that's the way it acts. CsQuery is open source and the source code is very readable, you're more than welcome to have a peek

Answer (score 2):

This would be sufficient :

```
$("a.result:first")   // will return a in div.first
```

`.parent().select('a')` seem's to be unnecessary.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/BRDqV/1/)

Comment: I know, but in my project it's smt like that             $("a:contains('something'):first")